# Що таке "полуда"?

Tags: значення-слів

"Мені мов полуда з очей спала" або "Вона нічого не чула, не розуміла, полуда впала їй на очі" (З усн. мови).

Що означають ці вирази? чи є різниця "полуда З..." чи "полуда на..." 
В словнику є таке пояснення:

> ПОЛУДА - Хто-небудь неправильно розуміє, сприймає, усвідомлює певні явища дійсності.

Як правильно вживати?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ПОЛУ́ДА](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0), и, ж.

> Білувата пляма на рогівці ока, яка спричиняється до сліпоти; більмо. [Кнур:] Дочко моя! дитино моя! Краще б я осліп або мені полуда
>   очі заслала, ніж приходиться мені бачить тебе у сьому чорному уборі
>   (Мирний, V, 1955, 92);
>
> **Зніма́ти (зня́ти, здира́ти, зде́рти і т. ін.) з оче́й полу́ду** — допомагати кому-небудь добре розібратися в чомусь, правильно зрозуміти
>   щось, раніше усвідомлене по-іншому. Театр знімає полуду з тих очей, що
>   не бачать, відкриває вуха тим, що не чують, будить нові думки і
>   почуття людини (Думки про театр, 1955, 80);
>
> **Полу́да з оче́й спада́є (спа́ла, опа́ла і т. ін.)** — про правильне
>   розуміння чогось раніше усвідомленого по-іншому. Всім міністрам і
>   слугам царським відразу мов полуда з очей спала. Таж се Лис! (Фр., IV,
>   1950, 96);
>
> **Полу́да на о́чі впа́ла кому** — хтось почав погано бачити. — Ти вже й
>   справді став старий та ще й недобачаєш; тобі на очі вже полуда впала,
>   — обізвався дід Грицай (Н.-Лев., IV, 1956, 218).

Тобто, фактор, який робив людину сліпою, усунули/усунувся, тепер людина бачить/розуміє те, що не могла побачити/зрозуміти до того. Тоді кажуть, що "полуда з очей спадає".

А може бути й зовсім навпаки: "полуда на очі впала". Тоді людина не бачить/розуміє того, що інші бачать/розуміють, або того, що раніше бачила/розуміла.